# An exercise from Stein's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $u$ is not an integer.Prove that

$$\sum_{n=-∞}^{∞} 
\frac{1}{(u+n)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin\pi u)^2}$$

by integrating $f(z)= \frac{\pi \cot\pi z}{(u+z)^2}$ over the circle $|z|=R_N=N+ 1/2$(N integral,$N\geq |u|$).

I know this exercise can be solved by using Fourier series, but I am trying to do it by using complex analysis.

And I have got that $\int_{|z|=R_N} f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum_{n=-∞}^{∞} \frac{1}{(u+n)^2}$.My question is how to relate it to the RHS?  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Look at the Cauchy integral formula for the derivative of a function: $$
f'(z) = \frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\oint {\frac{{f(t)}}{{(t - z)^2 }}dt} .
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f(z),-u)=-\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi u)}.
$$

Comment: Oh,I ignored the residue on -u.So I should add the residues and get 0?But i am still a lit  confused , how can i prove that the integral is 0?

Comment: This is a good question which I assumed  to be already solved by you. Here another hint: $$|\cot(x+iy)|^2=\frac{\sinh^2y+\cos^2x}{\sinh^2y+\sin^2x}.$$ Estimating the value of RHS subject to condition $x^2+y^2=(n+1/2)^2\pi^2\equiv R^2$ one should end up with a good upper bound for LHS.